# How to Show Attack Descriptions in Steven Universe: Unleash the Light for Nintendo Switch?

Tags: steven-universe-unleash-the-light

I've been playing Steven Universe: Unleash the Light for Nintendo Switch, and am having an issue making the attack descriptions show up consistently when selecting attacks.

As a result, there I'm running into a number of costly options I fear to try in game, because I have no idea what they do until I spend the star points to do them.

Is there a button combination I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since stumbled across the answer: Hold Down the "A" button to display the attack descriptions. Not the best choice, as the "A" button is also the "activate" button, and not every action option gives you the chance to cancel it, but that seems to be the way that the game works.

Comment: Don't forget you can accept your own answer if it resolved the issue.